# Discretizing a continuous probability distribution

Tags: julia

Recognizing that this may be as much a statistical question as a coding question, let's say I have a normal distribution created using Distributions.jl:

```
using Distributions

mydist = Normal(0, 0.2)
```

Is there a good, straightforward way that I should go about discretizing such a distribution in order to get a PMF as opposed to a PDF?

In R, I found that the [actuar package contains a function to discretize a continuous distribution](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/actuar/). I failed to find anything similar for Julia, but thought I'd check here before rolling my own.

Comment: When you say discretize what do you mean? Do you want to end up with something like a Markov chain that approximates the distribution?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't an inbuilt function to do it, but you can use a range object, combined with the `cdf` and `diff` functions to compute the values:

```
using Distributions
mydist = Normal(0, 0.2)
r = -3:0.1:3
d = diff(cdf(mydist, r))
```